# progress on $.when call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am trying to do some AJAX call using `$.when` and `$.then` functions. 
I am using these functions to fill a `template` and so , in the meanwhile , I want to fill the form that I will fill with some message like

> "loading data.. please wait"

I found out that there is a `progress` functions but it works only with `notify`. I searched through the community and I noticed that it is used with the `promise` call. I did not really get the meaning of `promise` and how deferred objects are working in my script.

This is my script :

```
         $.when(e.get_info('get_utente'))
            }).then(function(data){
                 $('#username').val(data.username);
                 $('#email').val(data.email);
         })
```

I would like to insert progress beetween this two calls. 
Sorry if there's some misunderstanding , but 'till now I was using `ASYNC : false` , and after i noticed that is a really bad idea I found out deferred objects , but i dindn't get at all it's logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The progress callback doesn't really apply to ajax requests at this time.

Instead, do your "loading data.. please wait" message before `$.when`.

Also, you don't need `$.when` at all, just do

```
$("#loading").show();
e.get_info('get_utente').done(function(data){
    $("#loading").hide();
    $('#username').val(data.username);
    $('#email').val(data.email);
});
```

`$.when` is only needed if you need to run something when 2 or more promise objects are complete. For a single promise object, it is not needed.

Comment: First of all ,good answer. Can you explain me better the meaning of using $.when?

Comment: $.when is good for when you need to do something when two different ajax requests complete rather than just 1 ajax request. You'll get one handler for both rather than one handler each request.

Comment: So if i use $.when with two ajax requests it will wait that both are completed?

Comment: Correct. And in that case, you can still use .done() rather than .then(), .then() has other uses, more than just the success callback. You can read more about jQuery deferred objects here: http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/