# Asynchronous Javascript in a synchronous manner (esp) in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, asynchronous, promise

I'm a bit new to JS async programming which I'm using in Phonegap. I have a function call

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,onFSWin , onFSFail);

var onFSWin = function(fileSystem) {        
  fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Icenium Demo", {create: false, exclusive: false}, onGetDirectoryWin, onGetDirectoryFail);
}
```

This callback works but it's starting to get quite messy when there is a chain of 4-5 calls. I've tried this

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
function(filesystem){
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Icenium Demo", {create: false, exclusive: false},    onGetDirectoryWin, onGetDirectoryFail); 
       }, onFSFail);
```

But it sees filesystem as undefined so a few questions:

1. Is the error Phonegap not accepting anonymous functions in this way
2. I'm looking at promises and callbacks in Jquery but I'm struggling to get me head around it. Could anyone give me an example using the defer object. I've seen examples using pipe but that is deprecated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819651/progress-on-when-call/15819745#comment22502559_15819745  get a look, i asked this some hour ago.

Comment: Callbacks are frustrating, right? In F# callback chains are very easy - you can use F# Async. It looks like synchronous code, but isn't. F# Async compiles to JavaScript with WebSharper, PhoneGap support is coming too.

Comment: Maybe this is just variable/function scope issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think the deferred pattern won't work with Phonegap it doesn't return deferred objects. However the video was very useful in explaining the promise pattern. Here is some basic code I got working for what it's worth

```
var step1 = $.getJSON('/test1.txt', function (data) {
return data;
});



var step2 = $.getJSON('/test2.txt', function (data) {
return data;
});

var processStep1 = function (data) {
var d1 = data.one;
alert(d1);
return $.getJSON('/test2.txt', function (data) {
    return data;
});
```

}

```
var processStep2 = function (data) {
$.each(data, function (key, val) {
    alert(val);
});
}

step1.then(processStep1).then(processStep2);
```

Comment: Those `function(data){ return data; })` bits are completely redundant.